# Adicionar todos os grupos solucionadores do Select Box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho um Select Box com alguns grupos solucionadores e um botão para adicioná-los ao banco. Ao clicar no botão, eu adiciono o grupo solucionador ao banco. Mas isso é feito um de cada vez. Gostaria de fazer isso tudo de vez.

Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
<%= form_for(@solver_group_user, url: admin_user_create_permission_contract_group_path, html: {class: 'ui form'}) do |f| %>
  <div class="two fields">
    <div class="fifteen wide field">
      <%= f.select(
        :solver_group_id,
        options_for_select(SolverGroup.where(contract: @contract, enable: 1).where.not(id: @user.solver_group).order(:name).map{
          |v| [v.name, v.id]
        }),
        {},
        {class: 'ui dropdown search menu_dropdown'}
      ) %>
    </div>

    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
    <div class="two wide field">
      <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'circular small ui blue icon button') do %>
        <i class="icon save"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, estas usando nested_attributes para passar os parametros?

Tenta o seguinte

```
def solver_group_user_params
 params(:solver_group_user).require(:seus_campos, solver_group_attributes: [])
end
```

Ficou meio confuso, então se puder dar uma esclarecida, agradeço.

Espero ter ajudado :)